# How do I get a str from this charField?

Tags: django

I have been trying to follow documentation but I keep getting the error:

> 'issues has no attribute content"

My goal is that i need a temp variable to hold data until I commit it to my actual database.

So when reading the code, content is basically tmp, and logComments is when I actually want to commit it to the database. Im trying to develop history tracking of who edited what, and when. However, whenever I call `instance.logComments = formIssues.__str__()` I keep getting that error even though ive defined a to string method. Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

```
class issues(ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,max_length=500, label='')
```

forms.py

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.content)

class Meta:
    model = History
    fields = ['content']
    widgets = {'content': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 50, 'rows': 30})}
    labels = {'content': ""}
```

views.py

```
formIssues = issues(request.POST or None)

   #This is for saving the issues textbox
if request.method == 'POST' and formIssues.is_valid() and 'Submit Issue' in request.POST:
    #History.logComments = formIssues
    instance = formIssues.save(commit=False)
    instance.logComments = formIssues.__str__()
    instance.projectID = 1337
    instance.userID = request.user
    instance.commentType = "Issue"
    instance.save()
```

models.py

```
class History(models.Model):

    projectID = models.IntegerField()
    userID = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    logComments = models.TextField(max_length=500, default='')
    commentType = models.CharField(max_length=20, default ='')
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

Comment: Why not just get it from the cleaned data as you normally would?..

Comment: I am new to django, can you please elaborate? I have heard the concept of cleaned data but I dont really understand it.

Comment: Its covered extensively in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/).

Comment: in which one though? is it specific for the forms, or do i need to look at the modelform one? Im a tad confused on which elements go where. sorry for being stupid, just looking for some understanding

Answer (score 1):

There are number of misconceptions here, and it's hard to understand where you have got them from.

Firstly, the error message is quite clear: your form's `__str__` method points to `self.content`, but the form class does not have a `content` attribute. It has a set of fields, one of which is `content`, but you can't access it via `self.content`; you wouldn't want to anyway, as the string representation of a field is an HTML input, which is how the form renders the fields on the template.

Secondly, the documentation is also clear about how to actually access the submitted data: via the form's `cleaned_data` dictionary. So in your case the content value would be `form.cleaned_data['content']`.

But thirdly, you don't need to do that anyway. `form.save()` already populates the model instance with the data from the form. There is no need to set it again.

You should go back and read the forms documentation: there is a [full explanation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django) of how to create a form and use it in the view.

Finally, even if you did for some reason need to access the string representation of anything, you should never call a double-underscore method directly. The way to do this in Python is always via the built-in functions: in this case, `str(formIssues)`.